# How to make Ajax Calendar Extender cause postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a textbox, Ajax Calendar Extender and a lable, I want to update the lable when date changed though serverside code, how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply fix the problem by using text onChange client side event, and wrote the following jQuery/JS code

```
function doTxtFromDatePostBack() {
  var txtDateFrom = jQuery('input[id*="txtDateFrom"]');
  setTimeout(__doPostBack(txtDateFrom.attr('id'),''), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the AutoPostBack property of the TextBox and the TextChanged event on the code behind.

Comment: This is the simplest answer, was our solution too.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to surround the Label in an UpdatePanel, set the panel to update conditionally.  When you update the label's text. call YourUpdatePanel.Update()